How to check if every array is filled?
I'm writing a code for rock paper scissor.
I need a function to run everytime I click on a button, to check if every array inside of array is filled. If every arrray is filled with player markers (without anyone winning), i need it to return false and make the game end on a draw.
let arrayOne = [
                [],[],[],
                [],[],[],
                [],[],[],
];

function isBoardFilled() {
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayOne.length; i++) {
        const row = arrayOne[i];
        for (let j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
            if (row[j].length === 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true; 
}


 if (isBoardFilled()) {
        \\the game goes on.
    } else {
        \\the game end with a draw.
    }

When i try to run the code, it just iterates over the first array and just ends the game on a draw.
I hope you understand what I mean.
Thank you all in advance.

As arrayOne is currently defined, there is no nested structure, so in each iteration of the outer loop row will be an empty array and the inner loop won't be executed (because row.length === 0) But your function can only return false if the inner loop is iterated at least once. So no, the code you currently show cannot go into the "draw" branch, because isBoardFilled() will always return true

You can use Array::every():


let arrayOne = [
                [],[],[],
                [],[],[],
                [],[],[],
];

let arrayTwo = [
                [1],[1],[1],
                [1],[1],[1],
                [1],[1],[1],
];

function isBoardFilled(arr) {
  return arr.every(arr => arr.length);
}

console.log(isBoardFilled(arrayOne));
console.log(isBoardFilled(arrayTwo));




but how do i use this in a function? So if the function == True "do something", else "do something else"?

@Wrcnow added to the code
